# Changing the format of the label to refer tables in the same section

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, captions

I am trying to refer to different tables that are at the end of the table but the reference comes up the same:

```
\documentclass{article}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   REQUIRED PACKAGES AND  CONFIGURATIONS
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% CONFIGURATIONS
\usepackage{parskip} % For paragraph layout
\usepackage{setspace} % For using single or double spacing
\usepackage{emptypage} % To insert empty pages
\usepackage{multicol} % To write in multiple columns (executive summary)
\setlength\columnsep{15pt} % Column separation in executive summary
\setlength\parindent{20pt} % Indentation
\raggedbottom  


% PACKAGES FOR TITLES
\usepackage{titlesec}
% \titlespacing{\section}{left spacing}{before spacing}{after spacing}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3.4ex}{2.1ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{3.4ex}{1.7ex}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3.4ex}{1.05ex}
\usepackage{color}

% PACKAGES FOR LANGUAGE AND FONT
\usepackage[english]{babel} % The document is in English  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UTF8 encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Font encoding
\usepackage[12pt]{moresize} % Big fonts

% PACKAGES FOR IMAGES
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{transparent} % Enables transparent images
\usepackage{eso-pic} % For the background picture on the title page
%\usepackage{subfig} % Numbered and caption subfigures using \subfloat.
\usepackage{tikz} % A package for high-quality hand-made figures.
\usetikzlibrary{}
\graphicspath{{./Images/}} % Directory of the images
\usepackage{caption} % Coloured captions
\usepackage{xcolor} % Coloured captions
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,xcolor} % Coloured "Theorem"
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{alphalph}
%\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{%
%\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}%
%}%

%new command for subfloat caption numbering
\newcommand{\subfloat}[2][\empty]% #1=caption (optional), #2=body
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{#2}% measure image
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\wd0}
    \usebox0
    \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \else\caption{#1}
    \fi
  \end{minipage}
\egroup}


% STANDARD MATH PACKAGES
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq} % For braced-style systems of equations.
\usepackage{fix-cm} % To override original LaTeX restrictions on sizes

% PACKAGES FOR TABLES
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable} % Tables that can span several pages
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{placeins}

% PACKAGES FOR ALGORITHMS (PSEUDO-CODE)
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

% PACKAGES FOR REFERENCES & BIBLIOGRAPHY
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,menucolor=black,runcolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref} % Adds clickable links at references
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[square, numbers, sort&compress]{natbib} % Square brackets, citing references with numbers, citations sorted by appearance in the text and compressed
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} % You may use a different style adapted to your field

% OTHER PACKAGES
\usepackage{pdfpages} % To include a pdf file
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum} % DUMMY PACKAGE
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For the headers
\fancyhf{}

% Input of configuration file. Do not change config.tex file unless you really know what you are doing. 
\input{Configuration_Files/config}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NEW COMMANDS DEFINED
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------

% EXAMPLES OF NEW COMMANDS
\newcommand{\bea}{\begin{eqnarray}} % Shortcut for equation arrays
\newcommand{\eea}{\end{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\e}[1]{\times 10^{#1}}  % Powers of 10 notation

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesubsection.\arabic{table}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table 1}
\begin{tabular}{lcc} \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 \\ hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:tab1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Table 2}
\begin{tabular}{lcc} \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 \\ hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:tab2}
\end{table}

I want to refer to the table \ref{tab:tab1} and the table \ref{tab:tab2} with two different numbers here

\end{document}
```

I have included all the packages I am using as I am not sure which might matter.

For the caption I have used the new command

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesubsection.\arabic{table}}
```

and this shows the caption of the table as I want (x.x.x.1 and x.x.x.2), but when I use \ref it shows only the subsection and not the number of the table (x.x.x for both).

Comment: You get `0.0.1` and `0.0.2` which is the expected behaviour. However, it makes no sense here. Use `\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}}` or use a `\section` and `\subsection` before you use a `table` anvironment.

Comment: I edited the question to include a section and a subsection, but that doesn't change my problem. In the caption of the table it shows the desired numbering x.x.x.1 and x.x.x.2 but the reference for both in the text is x.x.x

Comment: Your (current) MWE runs fine if you remove `\input{Configuration_Files/config}`.  Needless to say, it doesn't work at all for us with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get, if I comment your `\input{...}`

[image]

running pdflatex and up-to-date TL2022

Comment: I am using pftLatex version 2021, would that make a difference? I can't really find why it is not the same in my file

Comment: it maybe a problem with your contents of `\input{Configuration_Files/config}`. Comment the file out and try again. If it works than that file is the problem.